# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'net'

Tags: python, image, opencv

When the following code is executed, there is an error occurred.
Is there any other lib to be installed or imported?

```
import cv2
.....
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB = True, crop = False)

net.setInput(blob)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-b2dc4506da44> in <module>
----> 1 cv2.net.setInput(blob)

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'net'
```

Comment: Try after installing `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: you could check in Google `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'net'` - maybe you would have answer few hours ago.